# Do not update specific custom field on save_post in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields, wp-admin

As several fields are updated programmatically, I want those not to be updated when a post is saved or updated inside the `wp-admin` dashboard.

For example, the [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/) repeater field named `tickets` must not be saved during backend editing and when the post is saved or updated (because entries that are added programmatically during the time the post is edited are deleted when saved).

**My idea:** Before a post is updated, save values of `tickets` right before that post is saved using `acf/save_post` [before save](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/) and then [`update_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/) using `acf/save_post` again [after save](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/).

I know that you rightfully ask for the own approaches and attempts at solutions. Unfortunately, I don't have any. I have no idea how to combine these two `acf/save_post` correctly. If this is the right approach at all. That's why I would be all the more grateful for your help and support.

**Thank you so much!**

Answer (score 1):

I had a scenario similar to this where I didn't want users to be able to manually update fields. I created a function that would let me use an ACF filter to disable the specific fields. It looked like this:

```
function vgs_set_acf_fields_to_disabled( $field ) {
    global $post;

    if ( isset( $post ) ) {
        $field['disabled'] = 1;
    }
    return $field;
}
add_filter( 'acf/load_field/name=tickets', 'vgs_set_acf_fields_to_disabled' );
```

Then, if you have more fields, you can add more `add_filter` lines and simply update the `name` variable to match your ACF field name.

Maybe this will work for you as well?

Comment: thank you for your support. i'll try this tomorrow and give you feedback. thank you. thank you. appreciate it.

Comment: no need to put this inside a save_post hook, @vegasgeek?

Comment: This is not working in my case. Though it is impossible to edit that field inside the dashboard, row entries that were made programmatically meanwhile are overwritten by saving the post. But thanks for your help.

Comment: Aww dang. I thought by having the fields disabled, it stopped their info from being sent as part of the save as well.